# How to check if element has text-shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, css

How do I check if a element has text-shadow set in the CSS ?

With jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css), Luke.

```
var ts = $('some element selector here').css('text-shadow');
console.log(ts);
```

---

Don't believe me? [See for yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/SNaau/)

[image]

Comment: that means it doesn't have a text-shadow set

Comment: css: `a{text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;}` ..code is just like yours

Comment: @Shadow it works. I know it does. See my edit. **This is not the problem you're looking for.**

Comment: hey, where does that `$$$` link go in your toolbar?

Comment: @Shadow heh, forgot to screenshot without the bookmarks bar `:P` Since you asked, though, `$$$` only has [one bookmark](http://finance.yahoo.com/banking-budgeting/article/110829/a-sound-strategy-for-an-uncertain-time) right now (rather unused at the moment)

Comment: Doesn't work when I try it, either.  The DOM element's `style` and `currentStyle` objects don't have anything in their textShadow properties. Time for a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!$('elementSelector').css('text-shadow')){
   //No text-shadow.
}
```

Comment: `if(!$('some element selector here').css('text-shadow')){` Gee, that looks familiar...

Comment: @patrick - I just copied the selector from Matt's answer, the credit goes to him :)